# TypeScript / JavaScript: How to scan for all global classes (and filter by super class)?

Tags: javascript, reflection, typescript, introspection, scanning

1) In TypeScript, how can I find all classes defined at global level?
2) How can I filter them by super class?

I have model classes, which extend `FrameModel`.
These are not known before runtime (pluggable).
So I want to get a list of subclasses of `FrameModel`.

This is my attempt:

```
public static scan()
{
    this.mapping = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        var key = props[i];
        var val = window[key];
        console.log(`Key: ${key} Val: ${val} ${typeof val}`);
        if (val == null)
            continue;
        if (typeof val !== 'function')
            continue;
        if (val.prototype == void 0)
            continue;
        if (val.prototype.constructor !== FrameModel)
            continue;
        this.mapping[key] == val; // Doesn't work
    }
}
```

What I consider problematic is:

1. The use of `window` - let's say it won't run in the browser. Then I need a global object in general. I've seen using `this` in some context, IIRC in a function which is called outside an object, to get the global object. Is that the "official" way?
2. `window[key]` doesn't work - *`Window` is not assignable to typeof `FrameModel`*
3. It scans all props of `Window`, not just `Functions`. I assume there's some smarter way to get a list of `Function`s.

TypeScript 1.8.
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20FrameModel%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Model%20metadata%0D%0A%09static%20discriminator%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09static%20graphPropertyMapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3Astring%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09static%20graphRelationMapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3Astring%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(vertexId%3A%20number)%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20vertexId%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getVertexId()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.vertexId%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20setVertexId(id%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.vertexId%20%3D%20id%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestGeneratorModel%20extends%20FrameModel%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20discriminator%3A%20string%20%3D%20%27TestGenerator%27%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20graphPropertyMapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3Astring%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%27boo%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27name%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rank%3A%20%27rank%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20graphRelationMapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3Astring%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20colonizes%3A%20%27colonizedPlanet%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20commands%3A%20%27ship%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20boo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rank%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20colonizedPlanet%3A%20TestPlanetModel%3B%20%2F%2F%20edge%20label%20%27colonizedPlanet%27%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20ship%3A%20TestShipModel%3B%20%2F%2F%20edge%20label%20%27ship%27%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestPlanetModel%20extends%20FrameModel%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20discriminator%3A%20string%20%3D%20%27TestPlanet%27%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20graphPropertyMapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3Astring%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27name%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20graphRelationMapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3Astring%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestShipModel%20extends%20FrameModel%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20discriminator%3A%20string%20%3D%20%27TestShip%27%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20graphPropertyMapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3Astring%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27name%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20graphRelationMapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3Astring%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20DiscriminatorMappingData%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20mapping%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20typeof%20FrameModel%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22TestShip%22%3A%20TestShipModel%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22TestGenerator%22%3A%20TestGeneratorModel%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22TestPlanet%22%3A%20TestPlanetModel%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20DiscriminatorMapping%20extends%20DiscriminatorMappingData%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20getModelClassByDiscriminator(discriminator%3A%20string)%3A%0D%0A%09%09%20typeof%20FrameModel%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.mapping%5Bdiscriminator%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20%22this%22%20should%20be%20ok%20with%20static%3A%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.typescriptlang.org%2Fplay%2F%23src%3Dclass%2520Foo%2520%257B%2520static%2520x%2520%253D%2520%2522A%2522%253B%2520%257D%250D%250Aclass%2520Foo2%2520extends%2520Foo%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509public%2520static%2520getX()%2520%257B%2520return%2520this.x%253B%2520%257D%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%257D%250D%250A%250D%250Aalert(Foo2.getX())%253B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20getDiscriminatorByModelClass(clazz%3A%20typeof%20FrameModel)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.mapping%5Bclazz.discriminator%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20scan()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DiscriminatorMapping.mapping%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20key%20in%20Object.keys(window))%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09var%20val%20%3D%20window%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(val%20%3D%3D%20null)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20continue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20val%20!%3D%3D%20%27object%27)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20continue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(val.constructor%20!%3D%3D%20Function)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20continue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(val.constructor.prototype%20!%3D%3D%20FrameModel)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20continue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DiscriminatorMapping.mapping%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20val%3B%20%2F%2F%20Doesn%27t%20work%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: You can't do that, what if I defined my class in a closure?

Comment: Ok, changed - I only care about classes defined at global level. I haven't seen a class defined in a closure in typescript, how does that look like?

Comment: Got it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3266

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps you, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: In a global scope, capture 'this' and store it for later.

Answer (score 0):

> These are not known before runtime (pluggable).

Magical introspection does not work well with JavaScript. You generally want some dependency framework (e.g the one that comes with angular driven by *explicit code* i.e. decorators)

I recommend looking into https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS as the DI framework of choice.

## More

Just for your curiosity:

> The use of window - let's say it won't run in the browser. Then I need a global object in general

If you use `global` webpack will automatically point it to `window` when bundling e.g. : `console.log(global); // Window`. Ofcourse in NodeJs it would be the global: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Setting up webpack for typescript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html